# Shopify - Shorten/change 'Sort By' filter list options (not just changing default order)

Tags: html, sorting, shopify, liquid

I want to reduce the number of options available for users to sort by on my website. The default list of options is too long (e.g. there is no need to sort alphabetically, which is one of the default options), and I'd possibly like to rephrase some of them too.

I believe the code below is the most relevant. I can't seem to find where the sort_options are stored. I am using the Debut theme.

Note that I am not trying to create any new criteria to sort-by, only to reduce the options and rename them.

```html
              {% if section.settings.sort_enable %}
                <div class="filters-toolbar__item-child">
                  {%- assign sort_by = collection.sort_by | default: collection.default_sort_by -%}
                  <label class="filters-toolbar__label select-label" for="SortBy">{{ 'collections.sorting.title' | t }}</label>
                  <div class="filters-toolbar__input-wrapper select-group">
                    <select name="sort_by" id="SortBy"
                      class="filters-toolbar__input hidden"
                      aria-describedby="a11y-refresh-page-message a11y-selection-message"
                      data-default-sortby="{{ collection.default_sort_by }}">
                      {%- for option in collection.sort_options -%}
                        <option value="{{ option.value }}" {% if option.value == sort_by %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ option.name }}</option>
                      {%- endfor -%}
                    </select>
                    {% include 'icon-chevron-down' %}
                  </div>
                </div>
              {% endif %}
```

Comment: It looks like you have a class named collection where you have all sorting options. You may try looking for this class and delete sorting options there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a variable with option keys you want to hide and then just check whether the current option key is a part of that variable within the `for` loop.

```
{%- assign sortOptionsToSkip = "title-ascending,title-descending" -%}
{%- for option in collection.sort_options -%}
    {%- if sortOptionsToSkip contains option.value -%}
      {%- continue -%}
  {%- endif -%}
  <option value="{{ option.value }}" {% if option.value == sort_by %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ option.name }}</option>
{%- endfor -%}
```

Or just use the following if you only need to hide the alphabetical sort options:

```
{%- for option in collection.sort_options -%}
  {%- if option.value contains "title" -%}
    {%- continue -%}
  {%- endif -%}
  <option value="{{ option.value }}" {% if option.value == sort_by %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ option.name }}</option>
{%- endfor -%}
```

---

Use [`case/when` control flow tags](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/tags/control-flow-tags#case-when) to use other option names, again by matching it by key.

```
{%- for option in collection.sort_options -%}
  <option value="{{ option.value }}" {% if option.value == sort_by %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>
    {% case option.value %}
        {%- when "best-selling" -%}
          Best
      {%- when "created-ascending" -%}
            Old first
      {%- else -%}
          {{ option.name }}
      {%- endcase -%}
    </option>
{%- endfor -%}
```